# I need to extract text from table on every line that the data that i'm looking for appears

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

This is more than likely simple but I can't find a way to do it using Selenium webdriver.
I have table and from that table I need to select some data.
I can use the first 3 fields as keys the forth field is data.

example:

```
Low      wild     us       crash.
key1     key2     key3     key4
```

I need to loop though the file stuffing key4 into an array till I reach the end of 
the webpage.

this is the xpath for the first line of the table.

```
html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1] <key1>
html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2] <key2>
html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[3] <key3>
html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[4] <key4>
```

if I were coding is ruby I could just use 'nokogiri' if I were using perl I could just use
regex's...

Comment: So why don't you use Java's regex? I would help but I don't understand your question.